# Verify a signature using a certificate RSA Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, cryptography, rsa, cryptojs

I am attempting to verify a signature with a certificate. We have to download the required certificate from the CA, verify the certificate, then verify the signature. I have no idea, and I'm hoping someone can shed some light. Here's what I have / know so far.

To sign a message, I used the following code:

```
function sign(sk, m, certname) {
var key = new RSAKey();
key.setPrivate(sk.n, sk.e, sk.d);
var h = CryptoJS.SHA256(JSON.stringify(m)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
h = new BigInteger(h, 16);
var sig = key.doPrivate(h).toString(16);
var obj = { "type": "SIGNED", "msg": m, "certname": certname, "sig": sig };
return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

To verify a signature, I used the following code:

```
function verify(pk, signed) {
var key = new RSAKey();
var s = JSON.stringify(signed.sig).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
s = new BigInteger(s, 16);
key.setPublic(pk.n, pk.e);
var v = key.doPublic(s).toString(16);
var h = CryptoJS.SHA256(JSON.stringify(signed.msg)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
return (v == h);
}
```

To verify a certificate, I used the following code: (EDIT: this is the new certificate verification function).

```
function verifyCertificate(signedCert, certname) {
var key = new RSAKey();
var s = JSON.stringify(signedCert.sig).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
s = new BigInteger(s, 16);
key.setPublic(CApk.n, CApk.e);
var v = key.doPublic(s).toString(16);
var h = CryptoJS.SHA256(JSON.stringify(signedCert.msg)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
return (v == h);
}
```

And that's that. Can anyone please help. I don't know how to go about this.

EDIT: Okay, I think I have solved my own question (with assistance from the responses). This is the code that returns all positive results:

```
function verifyWithCert(sig) {
// 1. Download the required certificate from the CA
// 2. Verify the certificate
// 3. Verify the message
var certKey = new RSAKey();
var loadedCert = loadCert(sig.certname);
var certS = JSON.stringify(loadedCert.sig).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
certS = new BigInteger(certS, 16);
certKey.setPublic(CApk.n, CApk.e);
var certV = certKey.doPublic(certS).toString(16);
var certH = CryptoJS.SHA256(JSON.stringify(loadedCert.msg)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
var verifyResult;
if (certV == certH) {
    verifyResult = true;
}
var Sigkey = new RSAKey();
var s = JSON.stringify(sig.sig).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
s = new BigInteger(s, 16);
Sigkey.setPublic(loadedCert.msg.subject.pk.n, loadedCert.msg.subject.pk.e);
var v = Sigkey.doPublic(s).toString(16);
var h = CryptoJS.SHA256(JSON.stringify(sig.msg)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
var verifySignature;
if (v == h) {
    verifySignature = true;
}
var result = { "certificateFound": loadedCert ,"certificateVerified": verifyResult ,"signatureVerified": verifySignature };
return result;
}
```

Comment: What kind of a class teaches JavaScript cryptography? That's the last thing you want anyone to do. http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: @ntoskrnl I know right? I hate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(A note to other members of StackOverflow, I am also in this class so there's a bit of stuff that I mention that comes out of nowhere in regards to variables and other references.)

In the verifyCertificate function:

```js
function verifyCertificate(signedCert, certname) {
    var loadedCert = loadCert(certname);

    // signedCert is the same as loadedCert above, the button runs the
    // loadCert function and outputs the contents into the textarea,
    // so the following will always be true.

    var originalSig = JSON.stringify(signedCert.sig);
    var loadedSig = JSON.stringify(loadedCert.sig);
    log(loadedSig);
    return (originalSig == loadedSig);
}
```

> How am I supposed to verify the certificate then? What am I comparing the loaded CA certificate to? I thought maybe compare the public key in the certificate to the public key used to sign the message but... I don't know. I'm very confused.

You're on the right track with that though, think about the verify() function, and the details contained in the CApk variable at the top of the file. Can you hash the message from the loadCert() JSON response and match it against the output from:

```js
function verify() {
    //[...]
    key.setPublic(pk.n, pk.e);
    //[...]
}
```

Assuming you change a few variables?

It's similar to the method I used at least, so I'm hoping it's right. I figure if you can hash the message using the details in CApk, and compare it to a hash of the message contained in the JSON response, that verifies the certificate. Hopefully.

Comment: I have adjusted the verify certificate function, and it works, but now I'm trying to apply that to the verify RSA signature and certificate one and it's just not working. so I'm lost again. I hate javascript. I have next to no experience wit it and this is just torture.

Comment: note: just edited the original question to add the new certverify function

Comment: Okay, I think I have it working. It says it's verifying everything with no errors etc. So I think it's right. Except... you know how he says his solutions for the core tasks are between 5 and 10 lines? well this is about 20 lines of code, so i don't know if I should be suspicious of my code. I'll add it to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in 'verify certificate' approach.
you need to test the signature of certificate with public key of CA given in 355a3_main to verify, the code given here will only verify your certificate and will give s false positive for rest

i think this should work

```
var loadedCert = loadCert(certname);
var originalSig = JSON.stringify(signedCert.sig);
var loadedSig = JSON.stringify(loadedCert.sig);
log(loadedSig,originalSig);

var key = new RSAKey();
var s = JSON.stringify(signedCert.sig).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
s = new BigInteger(s, 16);
key.setPublic(CApk.n, CApk.e);
var v = key.doPublic(s).toString(16);
var h = CryptoJS.SHA256(JSON.stringify(signedCert.msg)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

if (originalSig == loadedSig && v==h)
return true;
else
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

That being said what about the long message of arbitrary length?

Comment: yeah no. I just got stuck on that. I got the short message working but yeah... no long message haha

Comment: if we take modulo of s for long message with n should this work??
    ar m= asciiToHex(msg);
    var key = new RSAKey();
    var s = JSON.stringify(m).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    s= new BigInteger(s, 16);

Comment: we could but.... how in the hell to do that? you'd have to code in all the maths. we thought maybe splitting the message into separate blocks and enc/dec the separate blocks then joining together to return would work but... wow lots of work for a unit that is not "a programming unit" (or a "maths unit") as they keep telling us. so yeah... now we're trying something completely different involving symmetrical ciphers too. but it's not working (well encryption is... but description, not so much). we're lost haha

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Except... you know how he says his solutions for the core tasks are between 5 and 10 lines? well this is about 20 lines of code, so i don't know if I should be suspicious of my code
> ```

I used the function verify and verifycertificate again in the RSA signature verification with certificate function. That will make your code fairly short. and I really appreciate this post, you're all my life savers.